# Problems with wpa_supplicant and hostapd. Help!

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, hostapd, wpa-supplicant

I'm tryng to share my wireless network (`wlan0`), and I follow this tutorial: https://linuxalfi.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/connectify-for-linux-with-single-wireless-interface/

The problem is: If hostapd was started, I won't be able to connect to network to my network by using wpa_supplicant. On the other hand, if I connected to network, I cannot start hostapd. These two hostapd and wpa_supplicant cannot start altogether.

Here are errors when I try to start hostapd: 

`root@me:~# hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf 
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
Using interface new1 with hwaddr 84:4b:f5:4c:89:ab and ssid "Linux-Hotspot"
Failed to set beacon parameters
new1: Unable to setup interface.`

If hostapd was started, these errors generated if I use wpa_supplicant:

`Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
new0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
new0: SME: Trying to authenticate with ac:86:74:26:54:72 (SSID='Ktx My Dinh' freq=2432 MHz)
new0: SME: Authentication request to the driver failed
new0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED`

And here's `iw list`

`root@me:~$ sudo iw list
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x3
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x3
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO`

What can I do to fix these? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bottom of the iw list output for something like this:

```
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
       total <= 3, #channels <= 2
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
       total <= 4, #channels <= 1
```

(This is what my Raspberry Pi 3 shows for wlan0.)  Note that the device only supports a single channel between the two (managed and AP) interfaces.

Try changing your hostapd.conf so the channel specified matches that of the network you're trying to join.